# How to refresh an IFrame using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a webpage with an IFrame and a Button, once the button is pressed I need the IFrame to be refreshed. Is this possible, if so how? I searched and could not find any answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to reload an iframe using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-an-iframe-using-javascript)

Answer (score 192, accepted):

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('youriframe');
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```

Comment: It works for me in this version of Chrome: `Version 24.0.1312.56 Ubuntu 12.04 (24.0.1312.56-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)`

Comment: FYI - There is currently (as of January 2013) a Chromium project bug (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=172859) which causes iframe updates to add to document history.

Comment: If into iFrame change the page, this method lost the navigation

Comment: `var tmp_src = iframe.src; iframe.src = ''; iframe.src = tmp_src;`

Comment: changing src of the iframe, generates a new element, then if you have a reference of that iframe, you should do that:

`iframeEl.src = iframeEl.src;
iframeEl = iframeEl.parentNode.getElementById('your-iframe-id');`

Comment: this perfectly work for me in chrome `document.getElementById('frame_id').contentDocument.location.reload(true);`

Comment: @MianHaseeb It has already been mentioned in other answer below; also it works only for same-origin iframe.

Comment: I've tried this answer and location.reload(true), both failed. The only workable code is @lyfing's.

Answer (score 115):

This should help:

```
document.getElementById('FrameID').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
```

EDIT: Fixed the object name as per @Joro's comment.

Comment: This is not working in IE9. You should use contentWindow instead contentDocument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Additionally, If you must positively cause a refresh to another page to another within the iframe then instead of `reload(true)` you would use this: `document.getElementById('FrameID').contentWindow.location.replace(new_url);`

Comment: This does not work with iframes with different origins (protocol, hostname or port).

Answer (score 28):

provided the iframe is loaded from the same domain, you can do this, which makes a little more sense:

```
iframe.contentWindow.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 7):

Works for IE, Mozzila, Chrome

```
document.getElementById('YOUR IFRAME').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this simple method

```
function reloadFrame(iFrame) {

    iFrame.parentNode.replaceChild(iFrame.cloneNode(), iFrame);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Resetting the src attribute directly:

```
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```

Resetting the src with a time stamp for cache busting:

```
iframe.src =  iframe.src.split("?")[0] + "?_=" + new Date().getTime();
```

Clearing the src when query strings option is not possible (Data URI):

```
var wasSrc = iframe.src

iframe.onload = function() {
    iframe.onload = undefined;
    iframe.src = wasSrc;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

2017:

If it in on same domain just :

```
iframe.contentWindow.location.reload();
```

will work.

Answer (score 2):

Got this from [here](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/468654-refresh-iframe)

```
var f = document.getElementById('iframe1');
f.src = f.src;
```

Comment: If into iFrame change the page, this method lost the navigation

Answer (score 2):

If you use hash paths (like mywebsite.com/#/my/url) which might not refresh frames on switching hash:

```
<script>
    window.onhashchange = function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            let frame = document.getElementById('myFrame');
            if (frame !== null) {frame.replaceWith(frame);}
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Unfortunately, if you don't use the timeout JS may try to replace the frame before the page has finished loading the content (thus loading the old content). I'm not sure of the workaround yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the HTML snippet:

```
<td><iframe name="idFrame" id="idFrame" src="chat.txt" width="468" height="300"></iframe></td>
```

And my Javascript code:

```
window.onload = function(){
setInterval(function(){
    parent.frames['idFrame'].location.href = "chat.txt";
},1000);}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Multiple iFrames inside the page, then this script might be useful. I am asuming there is a specific value in the iFrame source which can be used to find the specific iFrame.

```
var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
var yourIframe = null
for(var i=0; i < iframes.length ;i++){
    var source =  iframes[i].attributes.src.nodeValue;
    if(source.indexOf('/yourSorce') > -1){
        yourIframe = iframes[i];
    }   
}
var iSource = yourIframe.attributes.src.nodeValue;
yourIframe.src = iSource;
```

Replace "/yourSource" with value you need.

Answer (score 0):

If your iframe's URL does not change, you can just recreate it.

If your iframe is not from the same origin (protocol scheme, hostname and port), you will not be able to know the current URL in the iframe, so you will need a script in the iframe document to exchange messages with its parent window (the page's window).

In the iframe document:

```
window.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (e.data === 'Please reload yourself') {
    var skipCache = true; // true === Shift+F5
    window.location.reload(skipCache);
  }
}
```

In your page:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('my-iframe');
var targetOrigin = iframe.src; // Use '*' if you don't care
iframe.postMessage('Please reload yourself', targetOrigin);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this:

Js:

```
function refreshFrame(){
    $('#myFrame').attr('src', "http://blablab.com?v=");
}
```

Html:

```
`<iframe id="myFrame" src=""></iframe>`
```

JS Fiddle  : https://jsfiddle.net/wpb20vzx/

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the popular JavaScript _library_ called jQuery.

Comment: What would Math.round() do? It looks totally useless here.

Comment: Hi I used Math.round() Because Some Browser can cache Url - page so refresh not working.