# Force a window.onload event in javascript

Tags: javascript

Ok, I am going to rephrase my request as I think based on some of the answers, it got convoluted.  All I am looking for is if there is a javascript command to fire the onload event from the javascript in the parent.  A line of code such as:
`document.getElementById('FrameID').fire.onload();`
or if this cannot be done.

I am brainstorming an application where I am going to preload some iframes with url's, say 10 of them.  I am then going to rotate them by hiding and displaying the frames.  I want to be able to fire a window onload event after the active frame is displayed without reloading the page so the page will act as if it is fresh if it has an onload event. Can I do this?  The pages may or may not have a window onload event.

Comment: fire a window onload event where?  in the parent window?  Or in a given iframe's window?

Comment: The javascript would be in the parent which is running the show.

Comment: One more question - plain ol' JavaScript, or jQuery, etc.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654017/how-to-expose-iframes-dom-using-jquery

Comment: Either, but plain ol javascript would be preferred.  I have not written any code yet, just trying to get through this hurdle in my methodology.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is the current method for re-emitting the `load` event:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Browser compatibility:

- Chrome: 15+
- Firefox: 11+
- Microsoft Edge: all versions
- Opera: 11.60+
- Safari: 6+
- Internet Explorer: none (see [Dave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9642997/4171542))

Comment: Doesn't work on that, uh, "browser" named Internet Explorer.

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't work in IE -- see text in the link: "This constructor is supported in most modern browsers (with Internet Explorer being the exception). For a more verbose approach (which works with Internet Explorer), see the old-fashioned way below."

Answer (score 14):

You need to re-emit the load event:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('Event');  
evt.initEvent('load', false, false);  
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Getting access to the `window` object will be the hard part, and I think it's only possible if the iframes are from the same domain as your page.

Comment: Is this method more browser compatible than the one using the Event object? I presume it is.

Comment: @OgierSchelvis No idea, it was half a decade ago. I think if you're needing to do this then you're kinda already in a realm of weirdness that I don't want to think about anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Document.createEvent() and Event.initEvent() are [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent).

Use `Event` constructor for now:

```
const evt = new Event('build')
window.dispatchEvent(evt)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about *iframe* slideshow where you want to display content from other pages, then you should check out this tutorial (instead of images simply add urls):
http://www.2webvideo.com/blog/easily-create-slideshow-with-iframe-tag

Comment: This is basically what I want to do, but swapping urls for the images does no good.  I do not want to reload them everytime, I want to be able to fire the onload event after display, basically refreshing the page without calling the server.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [tutorial](http://www.2webvideo.com/blog/easily-create-slideshow-with-iframe-tag) you can use:

```
document.getElementById("$FRAME_ID$").contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

Then simply add new ID or CLASS for each element, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2064863/1097415

Comment: Won't that force another call to the server though?  That is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: It will call the page content again in iframe (it will reload the content of iframe).