# refresh only Div on button click to get data from database (asp.net,Jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to get literal data from database to display news on homepage 
whenever I change data in database I have to refresh whole page to see new data in div.
What I want to do is to click a button on homepage should reload/refesh data only for div.
the below script reloads the whole page

```
 <script>
    $("button3").click(function(){
        $("#container").load('WebForm1.aspx #container');

</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="container">

<ul id="js-news" class="js-hidden" >
    <li class="news-item"><asp:Literal ID="news" runat="server" /></li>
    <li class="news-item"><asp:Literal ID="news1" runat="server" /></li>
    <li class="news-item"><asp:Literal ID="news2" runat="server" /></li>

</ul>
</div>        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

I hope you guys can help me out.Thanks
I believe I need AJAX or something :/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the runat Server attribute from your button, i think that should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You could put your data in a iframe and then use this [iframe refresh method.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064850/how-to-refresh-an-iframe-using-javascript)
More information on iframes [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

Comment: Thanks. But I do not prefer iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need server control to do that because it will do postback.. you can just use a HTML button

```
<input type="button" id="Button3" value="Button" />
```

another thing, if you need to reference server control in JavaScript like you doing you should use  .ClientID()

```
  $("<%=Button3.ClientID %>")
```

Comment: did not refreshed anything :(

Comment: No error.It was just a dummy button.Did not pull new data from db

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button3").click(function(e){
        $("#container").load('WebForm1.aspx #container');
        e.preventDefault();
}

<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" clientIdMode="static" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: I added a video and played it.and then refreshed.but it refreshed video too.did not worked :(

Comment: try running my code again, but remove this line: $("#container").load......

do look for error in firebug

Comment: sorry did not get you. if I remove the line how will it know which DIV to refresh??

Comment: i just want to see, if that line is causing the issue. Bu default, a button tends to postback, no matter what you do. You can prevent postback, using preventdefault but if there are any js errors, then it postbacks automatically.

Comment: I am using button with runat server so it will post back.If I remove it doesn't but it also does not pull new db data.

Comment: This means the line i was asking you to remove has errors, probably the page path or something is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
    $("button3").click(function(){
        $("#container").load('WebForm1.aspx #container > *');
       });

</script>
```