# iFrame strange behaviour in loading a page in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint, iframe

In a SharePoint site page i'm displaying some IIS hosted ASP.NET web pages by using an iFrame(created by using CDATA tag in Content Editor Web Part). In my SharePoint site page i wrote a javascript function to return some value and to append the returned value as a query string in the src atrribute of that iframe.

Here i am perfectly able to change the src attribute of iFrame. But the problem is sometimes the ASP.NET pages that are being displayed by a different query string parameters being append to their page urls. I came to know that these wrong values are nothing but the returned values of a user who accessed the SharePoint site page simultaneously even i though the src attribute of iFrame is pointing correct url with exact query string parameters.

So i thought either the iFrame is being cached or in between the gap of javascript function execution to form src of iframe and to load the content with pointing to the formed url somehow the content page is being loaded with wrong url which doesn't make any sense. I am unable to find out the issue. Can someone guide me in this issue.Thanks in Advance

Comment: You may need to reload the iFrame.  Look at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064850/how-to-refresh-an-iframe-using-javascript

Comment: Hey @CMKanode thanks for the quick reply. But i tried that also unfortunately no luck. Can suggest anything else ?

Comment: Have you checked for any errors via the Developer Tools in the browser?  Also, you may want to output your values to the console, so that you can verify.

Comment: Yeah @CM Kanode I checked in the developer tools and there iframe is having correct url with correct query string being appended but the form the iframe is loading is having previously accessed user information.