# Refresh iframe on onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

How will I refresh each iframe onclick? Thanks!
Here's my js:

```
function Reload()
{
          $("#load").each(function()
          {
                    if($(this).is(':visible'))
                              $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
          });
}
```

My iframe:

```
<iframe src="SALES/add.php" id="load" width="100%" height="670px" frameborder="1" margin="0" padding="0" scrolling="yes">
                    </iframe>
```

Comment: Do you have duplicate IDs for iframes. IDs should be unique.

Comment: You can try this, should be working.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064850/how-to-refresh-an-iframe-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have duplicate IDs for iframe. IDs should be unique. For targetting all iframe you can use selector `$("iframe")`:

```
 $("iframe").each(function(){
         if($(this).is(':visible'))
           $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
 });
```

or

```
 $( 'iframe' ).attr('src',function(i,src){return src;});
```

**[Reference  answer by Šime Vidas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4249946/1719752)**