# Iframe refresh child page only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am creating a website with an `iframe`. 
The parent page has the menu and an area for the content.

If a visiter refreshes the page, then the parent page reverts to it's original state which is not always appropriate therefore I would like the child(content) page only to refresh when the visitor refreshes the page.
I used tag `name="link"` on the iframe of the page and tag `target="link"`, this name attribute was used to refere the value of the target attribute of a `<a>`.

I don't know if there is any way I can alter to stop the parent page refreshing. Can someone help me?

**EXEMPLE:**

```html
<ul id="nav"> 
  <li><a href="index.php" target="link">Home</a></li> 
  <li><a href="pages/about/about.php" target="link">Abut</a></li> 
  <li><a href="pages/what/what.php" target="link">What we do?</a> 
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Host</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Sistems</a></li> 
    </ul> 
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
</ul>

<div class="iframe">
  <iframe src="" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="link" width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to refresh an IFrame using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064850/how-to-refresh-an-iframe-using-javascript)

Comment: nop... not the same thing. I want press F5 not a button and none of those answers works on my case.