# Refresh locally hosted webpage text file in iframe every few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, refresh

I am hosting a very basic webpage on my local machine.  I use it to display the contents of several text files that are shows on a dedicated monitor.

I want to refresh the contents of the iframes only, namely JUST reload the text files, not refresh the entire webpage (which is what I have right now, which causes flickering).  I've tried several different approaches from multiple sources, but none either work correctly, or at all.

To be clear, I have Firefox and Chrome to work with.  Firefox is what I use the most.

This is my main HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Avionics</title>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/>
  <link href="Avionics.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div style="width:1453px;">
  <div id="shapeWORKORDERS" style="float:left; border-radius: 20px">
    <center><h1>ACTIVE WORK ORDERS</h1></center>
    <iframe id="iframe1" frameBorder="0" width="968" height="370" src="file:///J:/noah-files/AvionicsTV/WorkOrders.txt"></iframe>

    <center><h1>COMPLETED WORK ORDERS</h1></center>
    <iframe frameBorder="0" width="968" height="292" src="file:///J:/noah-files/AvionicsTV/CompletedWorkOrders.txt"></iframe>
  </div>

  <div id="shapeIFR" style="float:right; border-radius: 20px">
    <center><h1>IFR's</h1></center>
    <iframe frameBorder="0" width="363" height="185" src="file:///J:/noah-files/AvionicsTV/IFRs.txt"></iframe>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS:

```
body
{
   background-color: #95AFC2;
   color: #000000;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 10px;
   line-height: 1.1875;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

h1 {
    height: 0px;
}

#shapeWORKORDERS {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px;
  background-image: url('file:///J:/noah-files/AvionicsTV/abstract_wallpaper_1.jpg');
  -moz-transform: scale(1.10);
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.10);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
}

#shapeIFR {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px;
  background-image: url('file:///J:/noah-files/AvionicsTV/abstract_wallpaper_2.jpg');
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
}
```

Tried various javascript methods, and so far none of them have done anything, or mutilated the page after a load.  To be clear, I don't want to load another html file into the iFrame, just a text file that is already referenced.

My HTML is a bit rusty, so I'm working through it.

Comment: I have no idea what this has to do with java. Did you perhaps mean javascript? Java is to javascript as ham is to hamster: Utterly unrelated.

Comment: Java won't help you here as your browsers don't support Java. Retagged as "JavaScript" question

Comment: Yes, javascript.  My bad.  Didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by reloading it using js like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064850/how-to-refresh-an-iframe-using-javascript). But make it that it refreshes each minute this is an example:

```js
function reload(){
   var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
   for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
      iframes[i].src = iframe[i].src;
   }
}
let timerId = setInterval(reload, 60000);
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Added in the head section, as well as tried in the body.  Nothing happens.  Either I'm just not doing it right, or there is something else going on with my browsers.  I tried in both Chrome and Firefox.  Added inside a <script></script>

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: iframe[i] is undefined
    reload file:///J:/noah-files/AvionicsTV/AvionicsTest 5.html:11
    setInterval handler* file:///J:/noah-files/AvionicsTV/AvionicsTest 5.html:14
77 AvionicsTest 5.html:11:7

Comment: This occurred because it is `iframes` not `iframe`

Comment: Thank you @adam-basha.  That's what I needed.  This now works as expected.  I appreciate all the help!

Comment: You welcome @NoahGreene. But please mark my answer as solved