# How to refresh iframe using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to reload iframe without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to reload / refresh an iframe using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-refresh-an-iframe-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can take the iframe source and append a t=time()

```
document.getElementById('iframe').src = 'http://www.coolwebsite?t=' + time();
```