# Refresh iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, reload

I have an iframe on my page where you can checkout my latest web development pages, and so on. Is it possible to refresh it with regular JavaScript or jQuery?

```
<iframe src="projektit" style="width:100%; height:400px; border:none;" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

I'm thinking about something like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#iframe").html(data);
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Another option would be to make the page within the iframe refresh itself, either using a `<meta>` tag or a simple `window.setTimeout` setup... but can understand if you want the iframe to be refreshed externally. **Edit** unless I've misunderstood what you are trying to do

Comment: Not an option. The iframe must be only refreshed if the user wants.

Comment: Fair enough, that would make sense. In which case Gabe provides a good answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to reload an iframe using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-an-iframe-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XG3Ea/)

To refresh an iframe I would suggest just changing the `src` value.
Changing the `src` value will trigger the `iframe` to refresh.

```
$('#iframe').prop('src', url);
```

If you notice it's not refreshing, you could always attach a bogus query string value to the end of the url in the case of it being cached.

```
var q = new Date(); // use current date obj as query string value
$('#iframe').prop('src', url + '?q=' + q.getTime());
```

Comment: I'm unable to get this working, I'll make a fiddle about this.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen Google is not allowing you to use them as an iframe source. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/XG3Ea/

Comment: The code seems to be working... But not on my server... As I have managed to remove jquery from my page. But nope, it's not working.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen Perhaps you could use fiddler to see what requests are being made

Comment: It's probably something wrong in server configuration or something.

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe id="homepage" frameborder="1" width="400" height="300" src="http://jbcurtin.com/"></frame>
<script>
  var frame=$("#homepage")
  frame.attr('src',frame.attr('src'))
  // None jquery:
  var frame=document.getElementById('homepage')
  frame.src=frame.src;
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ekpAm/

Comment: This isn't actually doing anything.

Comment: This worked for me!   frame.src=frame.src; bind the latest url to the iframe