# Reload iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, iframe

- I have a jsp page with iframe in it.

for example: worklist.jsp

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <body>
 <iframe height="15%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" scrolling="no" src="menuBanner.jsp" style="border:0; padding: 0px; position:absolute;" width="960px">
</iframe>
<div><button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" value="Reload" id="reload"  onclick="reload();">Reload</button></div>
</body></head></html>
```

- On click of a button, i need to reload only iframe page.
- I tried the below script, but its reloading the whole page(worklist.jsp)

> function reload(){
>           location.reload();
>       }

Comment: check this : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-an-iframe-using-javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-an-iframe-using-javascript

Comment: This is totally not related to JSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function reload( {
  document.getElementById('iFrameID').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: Note, this only works if the iframe domain matches the parent domain.

Answer (score 3):

You can update/refresh the iframe by setting the src to the current src.

Here is an example.

```
var test = document.getElementById('iframeId');
test.src = iframe.src;
```

This way works for cross domain. The example in the comments are less hacky if iFrames are on the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('YourIFrameId');
iframe.src = iframe.src + '?c=' + Math.random();
```

i think without changing the src attribute you will not be able to reload your iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. 
Get the iframe src and assign again to the src of the iframe

```
<script>
function test()
  {
    $('#subpage_frame').attr('src',$('#subpage_frame').attr('src')) ;
  }
</script>

<iframe src="test.com" onload="Loaded();" id="subpage_frame"></iframe>

<button onclick="test();">Refresh button</button>
```