# Changing iframe src with JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I'm trying to pull a YouTube video id from an img and then pass it into an iframe to play an embedded video. My iframe is inside a div which is invisible until the img is clicked:

```
<div id="testimonialbackground" style="display:none;">  
    <a href="#" onclick="toggledisplay(this);">Click here</a> to close the video  
    <iframe id="testimonialframe" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>  
</div>  
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/x-ROeKGEYSk/1.jpg" onclick="toggledisplay(this);" />
```

And here's the JavaScript. It works fine until this line `elem.setAttribute('src', newsrc);`, at which point my page freezes up:

```
function toggledisplay(obj) {  
    var div = document.getElementById('testimonialbackground');  
    var elem = document.getElementById('testimonialframe');  
    if (div.style.display == "block") {  
        div.style.display = "none";  
        elem.setAttribute('src', "");  
    }  
    else {  
        div.style.display = "block";  
        var explosion = obj.src.split("/");  
        var newsrc = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + explosion[4] + "?autoplay=1";  
        elem.setAttribute('src', newsrc); // <---- BROKEN LINE RIGHT HERE
        elem.contentWindow.location.reload(); //to refresh the iframe  
    }  
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`src` is an attribute you can access directly so instead of your line `elem.setAttribute('src', newsrc);` just use this:

```
elem.src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + explosion[4] + "?autoplay=1";
```

Once you set the `src` there is no need to refresh the `iframe`, as setting the `src` will do that automatically. See [What's the best way to reload / refresh an iframe using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-an-iframe-using-javascript)
for more info on reloading `iframes`. (Basically it points out that you can set the `src` of an `iframe` to itself to refresh the `iframe`).