# Refresh iframe is working in chrome not in IE

Tags: javascript, iframe

```
function refreshIframe() {
    var ifr = document.getElementsByName('rightTrail')[0];
    ifr.src = ifr.src;
}




 <iframe id="rightTrail" name="rightTrail" scrolling="no" src="resources/JSP/RightTable.jsp" class="col last" width="300px" frameborder="0">        

</iframe>

 <div  style="float: left;">
 <button id="refershButton" type="button" onclick="refreshIframe()">Get The Latest Data</button>
 </div>
```

above code of refreshing the iframe is working fine in chrome not in IE.Please help

Comment: See: [What's the best way to reload an iframe using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-an-iframe-using-javascript) for info on how to accomplish what you are trying to do.


  [1]:

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

document.getElementById('iFrame').contentDocument.location.reload(true);