# Refresh aspx page in ASP.NET tab panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

On my ASP.NET page I am using an iframe and setting its source in code behind the page.

Markup

```
<asp:TabPanel ID="tabDocs" Enabled="false" HeaderText="Documents" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <iframe width="100%" height="600" id="frmDocs" frameborder="0" runat="server"></iframe>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>
```

Code Behind

```
 frmDocs.Attributes.Add("src", "/xyz.aspx?vType=EmpRpt&vid=" + EmpID.ToString)
```

There is a Create Report button on the page, which will save a report in the database and then show the file details (i.e. file name, size and etc.) on page `xyz.aspx`.

After saving the report I am using `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)` to refresh the whole page.

Is there any way of reloading just `xyz.aspx` showing it in a tab instead of reloading the whole page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an ASP.NET problem per se - just incidentally.

Consider using JavaScript to reload the `iframe` as [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86428/1810429) addresses.

One possibility per [one of the answers to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4062084/1810429) that you should be able to adapt for your needs is...

```
document.getElementById('frmDocs').src = document.getElementById('frmDocs').src
```

..., but there are others you can consider too.

Comment: i need to save the page first in code behind and then refresh tab

Comment: may be i can call javascript or jquery function from code behind page ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "blah", "YourJsFunction();", true);

Comment: @user1263981: Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: how do you include .js file path in ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock, i am adding jquery function in js file