# How to call js file function from code behind page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have following function in .js file and i need to call it from code behind page after saving a record.

I have registered scipt file in aspx page

**aspx file**

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/visit-flash-report.js"></script>
```

**.js file**

```
function reloadDocTab() {

alert('hello');
$('#frmDocs').attr('src', $('#frmDocs').attr('src'));
}
```

**Code behind page**

I have tried the function but it is not working

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(Me.[GetType](), "reload function", "return reloadDocTab();")
```

Comment: Try Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**.aspx**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/visit-flash-report.js"></script>
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litJS" />
```

**.cs**

```
litJS.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('hello');</script>";
```

If you dont need to execute the script on a different postback you might want to assign an empty string to the literal.

Comment: Do you use a Scriptmanager? Is it a callback or a full postback?

Comment: Thats what i am trying to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308243/refresh-aspx-page-in-asp-net-tab-panel

Comment: @user1263981 My bad... I edited my answer. I forgot to add the param "true", so that the script will be added within a script tag.

Comment: @user1263981 When guessing your .aspx structure you would need to insert a placeholder (in this case a literal) after the line where you reference your .js file. See my updated answer for more details

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your trying to do. You want to save the record on postback then when the page reloads call the javascript function.

Try this:

```
PageBody.Attributes.Add("onload", "reloadDocTab()");
```

Comment: no, i don't want to call reloadDocTab() on postback. I want to call it when i click certain button which will save record in DB and then refresh tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try **one** of these:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ScriptKey", "reloadDocTab()", true);
```

**OR**

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ScriptKey", "reloadDocTab()", true);
```

**OR**

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ScriptKey", "reloadDocTab()", true);
```

And i think you might need to refrence the .JS file in the head tag

```
<head runat="server">
    <script src="~/scripts/visit-flash-report.js"></script>
</head>
```