# I want to dynamically append the script in an iframe after onclick or onkeypress event fired

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an input which has a dynamic value as it's editable. Either **Onkeypress** in textarea or after **onclick** event fired on clicking the btn id it should append the input value in another **iframe** which is to be dynamic because input is to be changeable. So without page load the iframe's script innerHTML should refresh. I've done something but it's not working.

**HTML**

```
<textarea  id="inpt" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<div><input type="submit" value="append" id="btn" style="width:60px;height:20px;background:grey"></div><br>
<iframe id="fr" name="fr" style="width:300px;height:300px;"></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
            var _script = document.createElement('script');
            _script.type = 'text/javascript';
            var iFrame =  document.getElementById('fr'),
            iFrameBody,
            t = document.getElementById("inpt"),
            btn = document.getElementById('btn');

        function injectJS(content, val) {
           if ( iFrame.contentDocument ) 
           { 
             iFrameBody = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
           }
           else if ( iFrame.contentWindow ) 
           { 
             iFrameBody = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
           }
            iFrameBody.appendChild(content);
            content.innerHTML = val; 
            console.log(iFrameBody);    
        }

        //t.onkeypress = injectJS(_script, t.value);
        btn.onclick = injectJS(_script, t.value);
```

And here's the working demo. http://jsfiddle.net/n5fdywb9/

Comment: Referring to another article (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-an-iframe-using-javascript) I see that accessing the content of the frame goes like this: "document.getElementById('some_frame_id').contentWindow". So you probably can thus also access the document this way.

Comment: @PeterBranforn I've tried this too as i used in else if check here but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It should work.

```
var _script = document.createElement('script');
            _script.type = 'text/javascript';
            var iFrame =  document.getElementById('fr'),
            iFrameBody,
            t = document.getElementById("inpt"),
            btn = document.getElementById('btn');

        function injectJS(content, val) {
           if ( iFrame.contentDocument ) 
           { 
             iFrameBody = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
           }
           else if ( iFrame.contentWindow ) 
           { 
             iFrameBody = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
           }
            iFrameBody.appendChild(content);
            content.innerHTML = val; 
            console.log(iFrameBody);    
        }

        //btn.onclick = injectJS(_script, t.value);
        btn.addEventListener("click",(function(){injectJS(_script, t.value);}),false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append text to a `script` tag and `onclick` needs to be assigned to the element itself.

If the `onclick` is not associated in the HTML, then the `onclick` event is triggered when the page loads.

I have made the changes in the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5fdywb9/1/).

Comment: please check http://jsfiddle.net/n5fdywb9/3/ !!..

Comment: It is throwing an error.

Comment: which browser you are using .. :/

Comment: did you check try write `document.write('awesome');` int above area .. and click the buttons .. ?

Comment: Using Firefox 32.0.3, and the string which it is taking is throwing the error. I have fixed that in my fiddle.

Comment: its working here .. :/ .. you are using windows, mac, linux, or undefined .. .?

Comment: i don't know ... i m not getting any error .. can u ping the error log .. m using mac . tested this in all three browser.

Answer (score 0):

universal script to addEvent ..

```
     <textarea  id="inpt" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<div><input type="submit" value="append" id="btn" style="width:60px;height:20px;background:grey"></div><br>
<iframe id="fr" name="fr" style="width:300px;height:300px;"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('inpt').innerHTML = "document.write('awesome')";
if (typeof addEventListener !== "undefined") {
    addEvent = function (obj, evt, fn) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    };

    removeEvent = function (obj, evt, fn) {
        obj.removeEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    };
} else if (typeof attachEvent !== "undefined") {
    addEvent = function (obj, evt, fn) {
        var fnHash = "e_" + evt + fn;

        obj[fnHash] = function () {
            var type = event.type,
                relatedTarget = null;

            if (type === "mouseover" || type === "mouseout") {
                relatedTarget = (type === "mouseover") ? event.fromElement : event.toElement;
            }

            fn.call(obj, {
                target: event.srcElement,
                type: type,
                relatedTarget: relatedTarget,
                _event: event,
                preventDefault: function () {
                    this._event.returnValue = false;
                },
                stopPropagation: function () {
                    this._event.cancelBubble = true;
                }
            });
        };

        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, obj[fnHash]);
    };
}
var _script = document.createElement('script');
_script.type = 'text/javascript';
var iFrame = document.getElementById('fr'),
    iFrameBody,
    t = document.getElementById("inpt"),
    btn = document.getElementById('btn');

function injectJS(content, val) {
    removeJS();
    var windowVal;
    if (iFrame.contentDocument) {
        windowVal = iFrame.contentDocument;
        iFrameBody = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    } else if (iFrame.contentWindow) {
        windowVal = iFrame.contentWindow;
        iFrameBody = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    }
    content.innerHTML = val;
    iFrameBody.innerHTML = "";
    iFrameBody.appendChild(content);    
    if(isScriptTagIsThere()){       
        windowVal.location.href = "javascript:" + val;
    }
}
function isScriptTagIsThere(){
    if (iFrame.contentDocument) {
        iFrameScript = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    } else if (iFrame.contentWindow) {
        iFrameScript = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    }
    if (iFrameScript) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
function removeJS() {
    if (iFrame.contentDocument) {
        iFrameScript = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    } else if (iFrame.contentWindow) {
        iFrameScript = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    }
    if (iFrameScript) {
        iFrameScript.parentNode.removeChild(iFrameScript);
    }
}
addEvent(btn, "click", (function () {
    injectJS(_script, t.value);
}), false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n5fdywb9/6/

let me know if it helped ..

Comment: @rahul-send89 Only one problem is there when you run it second time the javascript inside iframe won't work. First time it works. I've modified your fiddle but still not working. Check http://jsfiddle.net/n5fdywb9/5/

Comment: @AkshayaRaghuvanshi : just updated my ans .. please check and revert .