# Redirect inside of iframe?

Tags: html, redirect, iframe

If I place iframe on my website, which links to another website, which isnt mine, and inside that iframe, on that website, someone clicks on a link that leads to another page, that redirection happens in my browsers main window, and not in iframe.

Is there any way I can make it so that It redirects inside iframe?

Comment: Duplicate?  See the third answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-refresh-an-iframe-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's not possible because you don't have control over what is loaded inside the iframe. So, if there is any anchor link that has `target="_parent"` , it's going to open the link in the parent frame.