# jquery reload dynamically added iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Have nice holidays!
I will also have a nice New Year if I solve the problem.
So I have an `iframe`, which is dynamically inserted in a certain place between page content. I need to reload the `iframe` on window resize, but I can't select it. I've tried:

```
$(window).on('resize', 'iframe', function(){
    //code for reloading
});
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-refresh-an-iframe-using-javascript

Comment: @Ianis, which answer is suitable for selection of dynamically added iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not reload:

```
$(window).on('resize', 'iframe', function () {
    // reload the iframe window.
    this.contentWindow.location.reload();
});
```

But this does:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
  // reload the iframe window.
  $('iframe').each(function () {
    this.contentWindow.location.reload();
  });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately. I've put console.log('test') inside the function and it doesn't show in console. I think it is because of dynamic nature of iframe

Comment: @АртурПипченко Check again! I said it will **not** reload. Changed the answer. See!

Comment: @АртурПипченко Let me know if the updated answer works.

Comment: @АртурПипченко It is not because of the dynamic nature, but you are executing the `resize` event on the `iframe` and not on `window`. Do you understand?