# Add javascript to iframe and execute it

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to do the following. Say I have html file and it contains blank iframe within it

```
<iframe id="preview"></iframe>
```

Now I need to write a script to update content of that iframe

```
var preview=document.getElementById("preview");
    preview.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + HTML_CODE_HERE;
```

Problem occurs when that code contains external CSS or javascript files, they just appear to not parse / execute.

How can I make iframe reload and re-run HTML parser for it's content?

Comment: I found a solution here: http://www.zomeoff.com/javascript-how-to-load-dynamic-contents-html-string-json-to-iframe/

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1.Why is the `src` of your iframe, an entire HTML page?Shouldn't you be creating an HTML page, say `page1.html`, and referring to that in your src?

2.You might be facing problems with external paths and CSS because the **path** that is given when the iframe is displayed.

3.For reloading an iframe, check this StackOverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-refresh-an-iframe-using-javascript).