# Update iframe with js

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How do i update this iframe every 5 sec with js?

```
<div><iframe src="http://bbkt.thna.dk/FsRubrik.aspx?Rubrik=3" frameborder="0" height="240" width="320" style="width: 100%; height: 195px;"></iframe></div>
```

It is on an cms system with content from another source.

Comment: Have you done any research or tried anything?  If so, please explain what you have tried and the issue you are having.

Comment: Appending `&?=0` to the src would refresh it, then you could do `&?=1` the next interval. Then put that in a setInterval().

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-refresh-an-iframe-using-javascript

Comment: Cross domain you may need to rewrite the frame or use target from a link