# How can I access and reload this iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a html page structure something like this,

```
<body>
  <table id = "a">
    <tr>
      <td id = "x"></td>
      <td id = "b">
         <div id = "y"></div>
         <div id = "c">
            <iframe id = "d"/>
          </div>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

I have tried using `getElementById()` on all elements then,

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('d');
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```

But, the `getElementById()` returns `null`. Please help!

**PS**: iframe is from the same domain. Need strictly JS code. No JQuery please.

**Edit**: How can i access the iframe ?

Comment: Where are you calling this code  of yours  ? at the bottom ?

Comment: getElementById() works fine see https://jsfiddle.net/fg6qzvay/

Comment: `getElementById()` does not work when I call it after `</table>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('some_frame_id').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

Look like a duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-refresh-an-iframe-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

try to using :

```
<body>
<table class= "a">
 <tr>
  <td class= "a"></td>
   <td class= "a">
     <div class= "a"></div>
     <div class= "a">
        <iframe class= "a"/>
      </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
```

and js :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("a");
```

Try it Yourself »