# html tags are displaying as it is when getting data from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, iframe

i have stored some html codes in mysql table using editors. it contains embed code of youtube video, so entry in mysql column is like this

```
This is a hello text. <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zAlX1V3lK5s"> </iframe><br>
```

i am making a jquery get call to get this data from mysql, the code i have used for this is

```
$.get(
     'test.php',
     function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        $('#test').html(response);
     }
);
```

the php code to fetch result is

```
mysql_connect("localhost", 'root', 'root');
mysql_select_db("dummy");

$rs = mysql_query("select dummy from demotable where id = xyz");
$r = mysql_fetch_array($rs);

echo $r['dummy']; //contains that string which includes iframe too
```

but when i am displaying the result to a div then it is not displaying video there but it is displaying string as it is the output i am getting on frontend div is

```
This is a strong beer. <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zAlX1V3lK5s"> </iframe><br>
```

how can i get the video there instead showing source ?

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated as of [tag:php-5.5]. So instead use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.
[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Comment: it is just an example i am using cake php to do ths thing but still it is displaying string , not converting embed code to video

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `<div>` tag too as:

```
echo '<div>'.$r['dummy'].'</div>';
```

Comment: this issue is with only iframe, images are displaying correctly.

Answer (score 0):

so finally i have found a solution. i have to do a minor tweak only with jquery. have a look on the code below

```
$.get(
   'test.php',
   function(response) {
      var res = $('<div/>').html(response).text();
      $('#test').html(response);
   }
);
```

it will decode the html and iframe will be there.

Answer (score -1):

I think you would need to force the iframe to load. According to [What’s the best way to reload / refresh an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/what-s-the-best-way-to-reload-refresh-an-iframe) this can be achieved with javascript like this:

`document.getElementById('some_frame_id').contentWindow.location.reload();`

But that would probably look like this in jquery:

`$('#test').find('iframe')[0].contentWindow.location.reload();`

Try that :)

Comment: this does not solve the issue. also <br> tag is displaying as it is, it should be  line break there. so this is something to do with variable of php. because if directly putting like this 
$('#test').html('This is a text. <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zAlX1V3lK5s"></iframe><br>');
then it is displaying iframe there.

Comment: this issue is with only iframe, images are displaying correctly.