# Auto refresh/reload four iframes in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, iframe, reload

I'm pretty NEW
so on the question:
I have 4 iframes on one page in WordPress showing some stats. I want to make them auto refresh (not the whole page) on certain amount of time, like every 3 second.

I've managed to do that for one only but whenever I try to add another one it  doesn't work. I hope there's a simple solution.

Here's the iframe:

```
<iframe id="idcw" src="http://web.ubercounter.com/charts/chart5?f=jsn&ext=1&pid=01edabc9-dd3c-41db-949b-9b6ee52e0af5&cid=&fromD=2018-06-26&toD=&fromT=16:48:14&toT=<=&lg=&r=0&fh=0&th=24&u=0&rt="></iframe>
```

And the JS I''ve putt in the Header:

```
<script>

window.setInterval("reloadIFrame1();", 60000);

function reloadIFrame1() {
 document.frames["idcw"].location.reload();
}

window.setInterval("reloadIFrame2();", 60000);

function reloadIFrame2() {
 document.getElementById('idcw').src = document.getElementById('idcw').src; 
}

</script>
```

PS: That was the only code I found on the internet working as it had to work. I tried with my very basic knowledge to add another 3 iframes to reload but only one refreshed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What’s the best way to reload / refresh an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/what-s-the-best-way-to-reload-refresh-an-iframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```js
setInterval(function(){ reloadIFrame2(); }, 5000);
  
function reloadIFrame2() {

 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("idcw");
 for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
  elements[i].src =  elements[i].src;
 }  
}
```

```html
<iframe class="idcw"  src="http://web.ubercounter.com/charts/chart5?f=jsn&ext=1&pid=01edabc9-dd3c-41db-949b-9b6ee52e0af5&cid=&fromD=2018-06-26&toD=&fromT=16:48:14&toT=<=&lg=&r=0&fh=0&th=24&u=0&rt="></iframe>

<iframe class="idcw"  src="http://web.ubercounter.com/charts/chart5?f=jsn&ext=1&pid=01edabc9-dd3c-41db-949b-9b6ee52e0af5&cid=&fromD=2018-06-26&toD=&fromT=16:48:14&toT=<=&lg=&r=0&fh=0&th=24&u=0&rt="></iframe>

<iframe class="idcw"  src="http://web.ubercounter.com/charts/chart5?f=jsn&ext=1&pid=01edabc9-dd3c-41db-949b-9b6ee52e0af5&cid=&fromD=2018-06-26&toD=&fromT=16:48:14&toT=<=&lg=&r=0&fh=0&th=24&u=0&rt="></iframe>


<iframe class="idcw"  src="http://web.ubercounter.com/charts/chart5?f=jsn&ext=1&pid=01edabc9-dd3c-41db-949b-9b6ee52e0af5&cid=&fromD=2018-06-26&toD=&fromT=16:48:14&toT=<=&lg=&r=0&fh=0&th=24&u=0&rt="></iframe>
```

Run this fiddle

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/asn7-zfvq