# Google Data not able to access embed url

Tags: looker-studio

I embedded data studio url in my web application and i'm not able to see the report and i'm getting this message, `Report cannot be viewed at this time`[image]

Answer (score 2):

The 'report cannot be viewed at this time' error is a bug on their side that a lot of people gave been getting lately -

https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/11462439?hl=en&dark=0

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar solution posted in the below link below

[Google Data Studio - Refresh data on embedded website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164686/google-data-studio-refresh-data-on-embedded-website)

Apart from that you can work on the refresh rate of the Data Studio Page